# Access Violation Exception Raised when Accessing a Dynamic 2D char Array

Tags: c++, arrays, class, dynamic

I have currently a problem with the following C++ class, which holds the model logic of a cube. The constructor creates a dynamic 2d char array with the following content:

```
[ [0,0,0,0,0,0],
  [1,1,1,1,1,1],
  [2,2,2,2,2,2], 
  [3,3,3,3,3,3],
  [4,4,4,4,4,4],
  [5,5,5,5,5,5] ].
```

CubeModel.h

```
#ifndef CUBEMODEL_H_INCLUDED
#define CUBEMODEL_H_INCLUDED

#include <iostream>

class CubeModel
{
private:
    const unsigned short m_faces;
    const unsigned short m_fields;

    char **m_cube_base_pointer;
public:
    CubeModel(const unsigned short faces, const unsigned short fields);
    ~CubeModel();

    void output();
};

#endif // CUBEMODEL_H_INCLUDED
```

CubeModel.cpp

```
#include "CubeModel.h"

CubeModel::CubeModel(const unsigned short faces, const unsigned short fields): m_faces(faces), m_fields(fields) {
    m_cube_base_pointer = new char*[m_faces];
    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < m_faces; ++i) {
        m_cube_base_pointer[i] = new char[m_fields * m_fields];
        memset(m_cube_base_pointer[i], i, sizeof m_cube_base_pointer[i]);
    }
}

CubeModel::~CubeModel() {
    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < m_faces; ++i) {
        std::cout << (int) m_cube_base_pointer[i][0];
        delete [] m_cube_base_pointer[i];
    }
    delete [] m_cube_base_pointer;
}

/*
    Console output of the cube model
*/
void CubeModel::output() {
    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < m_faces; ++i) {
        for (unsigned int j = 0; j < m_fields * m_fields; ++j) {
            std::cout << (int) m_cube_base_pointer[i][j] << std::endl;  // output the model
        }
    }
}
```

main.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include "CubeModel.h"

using namespace std;

int main() {
    CubeModel cube = CubeModel(6, 3);
    cube.output();

    system("PAUSE");

    return 0;
}
```

When I create a CubeModel object in the main function and call the output method, I got the following error message in Visual Studio:

Exception raised at 0x00FC1DC8 in Cube.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation at reading a position 0x00000000.

The exception is raised inside the output() method in CubeModel.

What I'm doing wrong here?

Comment: in the default constructor you use `DEFAULT_FACES`, i don't see where this is defined. Might be the issue

Comment: Why are you using raw pointers and `new` / `delete` at all? Doesn't a `std::vector<std::string>` fit your needs?

Comment: @Tyler No, that can't be the issue, the code won't even compile then.

Comment: I removed this constructor from the code. I've updated the code above ;-) I've forgot to removed it from this snippet of code. But that has nothing to do with this problem.

Comment: `sizeof m_cube_base_pointer[i]` in `memset()` may be the culprit.

Comment: Why are you using the `char` data type?  If you want 8 bit wide, you should prefer either `uint8_t` or `int8_t`.  The `char` can be signed, unsigned or char.  The *minimum* range for a char is 8-bits, there is nothing preventing an implementation from using 16-bits or 32 bits for a `char`.

Comment: If you must use an array, I recommend allocating a 1 dimensional array, then applying a formula for converting row & column addressing to an integer index.

Comment: And what exactly do you actually print in `output()`? Is `m_cube_base_pointer[0]` a null-terminated string? Data-modelling looks weird too: do you need to allocate space for `m_faces*m_fields*m_fields` characters?

Comment: @ThomasMatthews I've also considered that. Yes, I think it would be better to use a 1d array with the formula cube[NUM_FIELDS * face + field]

Comment: @ConstantineGeorgiou Sorry, I've casted it to int. I want to output the content of each field, as described in the array above

Comment: `Access violation at reading a position 0x00000000.` You have a nulllptr that you tried to dereference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The third argument of [memset](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/memset/) is the number of bytes you want to set.

However

```
sizeof m_cube_base_pointer[i]
```

will give you the size of the pointer, not the size of the dynamic array you just allocated. So in order to get the right number of bytes you want to set, you should do

```
sizeof(char) * m_fields * m_fields
```

instead. And your memset call should become this:

```
memset(m_cube_base_pointer[i], i, sizeof(char) * m_fields * m_fields);
```